# Find if the key and value pair exist in a json

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to see if a key and value pair exist in a JSON in python.

Here is what I have:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "model": "test"
        },
        {
            "model": "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried this:

```
jsondata = open("test.json",'r').read() 
fileData = json.loads(jsondata)

if "test" in [cars.model for cars in fileData]:
    print('test')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if "test" in [cars['model'] for cars in fileData['cars']]:
    print('test')
```

**Update:**

```
print([cars for cars in fileData['cars'] if cars['model']=='test'])
```

Need to just do a list comprehension

Comment: how do I print the model that matches?... it goes inside the if but now i want to print that exact model since im doing it dynamically

Comment: @HeelMega Now??

Answer (score 3):

The best way i suggest would be to use dict and exception handling. Whenever a particular key is not found the '[KeyError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError)' exception is raised, which would allow you to do the needful if the key does not exists.

In your case :

```
jsondata = open("test.json",'r').read() 
fileData = json.loads(jsondata)

try:
  cars = fileData['cars']
except KeyError:
  print("Missing cars key")
```

Hope it helps!